# PlatformNotSupportedException in CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("no") on .Net Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am getting `PlatformNotSupportedException` while trying to create a `CultureInfo`.

```
 CultureInfo ci =  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("no");
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What version of the Compact Framework are you targeting?

Comment: That could only work on a version of Windows Mobile that is localized to Norwegian.  The "compact" in Compact Framework.  You'd still never want to use the neutral culture.

Comment: @HansPassant What should I do to fix that ?

Comment: Is that something that is not supported in your SDK or does Norwegian need to be burned into the OS of your device?